# Unity 2D Animation Not Changing States

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a pretty simple question:

I've set up the Unity Animator, with a rudimentary "Idle" state and "WalkRight" state. There's a boolean I have to transition between Idle and WalkRight.

However, for some reason, I can't get my character to transition from Idle->WalkRight when WalkRight is true.

If I set WalkRight animation to be default and the boolean is false, it will transition to Idle, however not vice versa.

Here is an image of the issue in practice:

[image: Not transitioning!]

As you can see, WalkRight = true at the bottom, and (I believe) the transition is set up correctly on the right.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Wanna try to help.Could you send me project? valeriy.nikitin@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It hadn't saved my script properly, so it was using old code setting "WalkRight" to false.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to have a script that changes the WalkRight boolean when the player makes the correct input. Should look something like the following:

```
Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

anim.SetBool("WalkRight", true);
```

Comment: I actually have that exact code as well.

This is an AI-controlled character, so it's not going to be bound to input. However, regardless, if WalkRight == true, as shown above, shouldn't it be transitioning?